# Tornadofx Javafx - How to reload a view / component

Tags: javafx, kotlin, tornadofx

So its a basic question.
What I am trying to achieve is refreshing views from another views.

Lets say I have a view EmployeeTableView which shows a tabular representation of employees by doing a REST API call.
In another view, I have a the filter EmployeeFilterView wherein I have gender, salary range, employee type, etc.
I also have a userContext object in which I store the user preferences. So by default lets say I have stored the value of gender filter to be Male, salary range to be ALL, etc. This object is send as a parameter to the EmployeeTableView.

When the EmployeeTableView is loaded I do a restAPI call with the userContext values to get the employee details. So that works fine. Now I change the gender filter to Female and assign this value in my userContext.
Now if I could just reload the EmployeeTableView with the userContext object, the restapi call would get the updated values.

But how can I do that ?
Also suggest a better approach if you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EventBus is one valid solution to this. Another would be to use a ViewModel or Controller as the UserContext object and let that include the actual observable list of employees and then bind that list to the `TableView` in `EmployeeTableView`. Whenever the list in the context is updated, the TableView will update as well.

The filter view would call a function in the UserContext to perform the actual REST call and update the list of employees based on that.

You could create a separate EmployeeQuery object that can be injected into both the `EmployeeFilterView` and the `UserContext` so it can extract the selected filter values to perform the query. This query object contains a list of all the search parameters you want to pass to the server.

You could also consider creating a separate scope to keep these components separated if that makes sense to your architecture.

Exactly how you define these components are mostly a matter of taste, here is one suggestion. I used the `RangeSlider` from ControlsFX for the mock search UI.

To make it easier to imagine how this ties together, here is a screenshot:

(All names and salaries are fiction :)

[image: Employee App]

```
/**
 * The employee domain model, implementing JsonModel so it can be fetched 
 * via the REST API
 */
class Employee : JsonModel {
    val nameProperty = SimpleStringProperty()
    var name by nameProperty

    val salaryProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty()
    var salary by salaryProperty

    val genderProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<Gender>()
    var gender by genderProperty

    override fun updateModel(json: JsonObject) {
        with (json) {
            name = getString("name")
            salary = getInt("salary")
            gender = Gender.valueOf(getString("gender"))
        }
    }
}

enum class Gender { Male, Female }

/**
 * Container for the list of employees as well as a search function called by the filter
 * view whenever it should update the employee list.
 */
class EmployeeContext : Controller() {
    val api: Rest by inject()
    val query: EmployeeQuery by inject()
    val employees = SimpleListProperty<Employee>()

    fun search() {
        runAsync {
            FXCollections.observableArrayList(Employee().apply {
                name = "Edvin Syse"
                gender = Gender.Male
                salary = 200_000
            })
            //api.post("employees/query", query).list().toModel<Employee>()
        } ui {
            employees.value = it
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Query object used to define the query sent to the server
 */
class EmployeeQuery : ViewModel(), JsonModel {
    val genderProperty = SimpleObjectProperty<Gender>(Gender.Female)
    var gender by genderProperty

    val salaryMinProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(50_000)
    var salaryMin by salaryMinProperty

    val salaryMaxProperty = SimpleIntegerProperty(250_000)
    var salaryMax by salaryMaxProperty

    val salaryDescription = stringBinding(salaryMinProperty, salaryMaxProperty) {
        "$$salaryMin - $$salaryMax"
    }

    override fun toJSON(json: JsonBuilder) {
        with(json) {
            add("gender", gender.toString())
            add("salaryMin", salaryMin)
            add("salaryMax", salaryMax)
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The search/filter UI
 */
class EmployeeFilterView : View() {
    val query: EmployeeQuery by inject()
    val context: EmployeeContext by inject()

    override val root = form {
        fieldset("Employee Filter") {
            field("Gender") {
                combobox(query.genderProperty, Gender.values().toList())
            }
            field("Salary Range") {
                vbox {
                    alignment = Pos.CENTER
                    add(RangeSlider().apply {
                        max = 500_000.0
                        lowValueProperty().bindBidirectional(query.salaryMinProperty)
                        highValueProperty().bindBidirectional(query.salaryMaxProperty)
                    })
                    label(query.salaryDescription)
                }
            }
            button("Search").action {
                context.search()
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The UI that shows the search results
 */
class EmployeeTableView : View() {
    val context: EmployeeContext by inject()

    override val root = borderpane {
        center {
            tableview(context.employees) {
                column("Name", Employee::nameProperty)
                column("Gender", Employee::genderProperty)
                column("Salary", Employee::salaryProperty)
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A sample view that ties the filter UI and result UI together
 */
class MainView : View("Employee App") {
    override val root = hbox {
        add(EmployeeFilterView::class)
        add(EmployeeTableView::class)
    }
}
```

Comment: wow that was a neat way of doing it. Thanks !! helped me a lot.

Comment: Great! The ViewModel, and especially the ItemViewModel is a fantastic tool to bind disparate UI components together. I use it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Tornadofx -> EventBus

Basically, when I change any of the filters, I fire an even which rebuilds the Node with the updated values.

Not sure whether the approach is right, that's why still keeping it open for discussion.

Comment: Good call. I will post an answer with another suggestion tonight :)